# What is the difference between "my" and "my own" and "its" and "its" and "its own"?

Tags: difference, possessive-pronouns

What is the difference between "**my**" and "**my own**" and also what is the difference between "**its**"  and "**its**" and "**its own**"?

For example:

> This is **my** book.

Vs.

> This is **my own** book.

Or

> This is **its** cover.

Vs.

> This is **its own** cover.

Comment: Note that the last two examples are ungrammatical because they don't have a verb.

Answer (score 5):

The variant with "own" has a stronger sense of possession or ownership, and is often used to indicate that the possession is *exclusive* and not shared with anyone or anything else.

For example:

> Let's meet at my house.

Here, "my house" is just the place where I live.  I might or might not share that house with roommates or family; it's not really specified one way or another.

> I am saving money to buy my own house.

Here, I'm saying that my intent is to buy a house that belongs to me and only me. Maybe I live with roommates now, and I want to be more self-sufficient.

I find it difficult to imagine a situation where I would refer to a book's "own cover," but one common phrase where "its own" is used is "on its own merits."  For example:

> You should judge the plan on its own merits, not on the person who proposed it.

Again, this is using "its own" to be *exclusive*. It's saying you should only consider the good and bad points of the plan when judging it; you should not consider the good and bad points of the person who proposed the plan.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Kindly, could you refer also electrically to my examples?

Answer (score 2):

This answer could take pages, so let me just add to Canadian Yankee's answer.

In some contexts **own** could be paraphrased as "original".

> Is that your own hair, or a wig?
>
> Is that the book's own cover, or was it added by the library?

Sometimes **own** is an intensifier of the closeness of the relationship and could be paraphrased as "even his own":

> He's so crooked he'd cheat his own mother.

here, "even their own":

> Some animals have such a strong instinct to free themselves from  a trap that they will chew off their own foot to get loose.

Sometimes it means "by myself, with no interference or annoying suggestions from you":

> If you don't mind, I'd like to choose my own necktie, thank you.

Sometimes it means "not yours" or "not the one you have":

> You go on without me and I will meet you there. I'm going to take my own car.